# Why did transaction rollback during stage3CommitProcessing?

Tags: java, oracle, websphere, ibm-mq, distributed-transactions

In a Java program running in two Websphere nodes the following race scenario happens in a distributed transaction managed by Websphere Transaction Manager.  The transaction spans across a JMS (Websphere-MQ) Transaction Source and a Database (Oracle) Transaction Source.  I would like to understand

- Why this (Exception in Thread 2, at step B6) exception happened? 
  I expected no issues to happen.  Thread 2 had proceeded only after making sure T1 is locked in Transaction TX2, so it is natural that Thread 1 was waiting for T1 table lock (within Transaction TX1) to be released.  What I'm wondering about is that why did Thread 2 encounter a stage3CommitProcessing exception?  How could I get more details about it, as the exception doesn't breathe any informtaion about it?
- How to debug such transaction related race scenario?  I know it might be difficult to reproduce.  But I think there could be some Websphere related logs that I could enable to see what made the commit fail during stage3?  It would be great if someone could point me in that direction.
- How it could be avoided/resolved?

---

**Thread 1 (Running in Websphere node 1)**

```
A1: Start TX1
A2: Read messages (maximum of 1000 at a time) from Queue Q1
A3: LOCK TABLE T1 IN EXCLUSIVE MODE
        Got exception "ORA-02049": distributed transaction waiting for lock.  
Refer Log 1 for stack trace
```

---

**Thread 2 (Running in Websphere node 2)**

```
B1: Start TX2
B2: Read messages (maximum of 1000 at a time) from Queue Q1
B3: LOCK TABLE T1 IN EXCLUSIVE MODE
B4: Batch execute
    MERGE INTO T1 the messages read
B5: Batch insert messages into T2
B6: Commit TX2
    Got JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout). Refer Log 2 for stack trace.  This was while ***stage3CommitProcessing***.
```

---

***Log 1:***

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [LOCK TABLE T1 IN EXCLUSIVE MODE]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock

```
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:94)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:518)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.update(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:248)
at com.test.OracleTableLock.processMessage(OracleTableLock.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor833.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy153.receiveMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.test.BatchProcessor.processMessage(BatchProcessor.java:343)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor779.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy155.receiveMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor778.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run(MethodInvokingRunnable.java:65)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:453)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:329)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:162)
at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.TimerManagerTaskScheduler$TimerScheduledFuture.timerExpired(TimerManagerTaskScheduler.java:112)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.TimerImpl.callListenerMethod(TimerImpl.java:298)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.GenericTimer.run(GenericTimer.java:216)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:264)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:495)
at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:131)
at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:89)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:335)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1146)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.TimerImpl.runListenerAsCJWork(TimerImpl.java:425)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.fireAlarm(_Alarm.java:333)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:230)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock

at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:942)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1706)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1674)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:275)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.pmiExecuteUpdate(WSJdbcStatement.java:1683)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcStatement.java:1041)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:508)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:395)
... 50 more
```

---

***Log 2:***

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at com.test.BatchProcessor.processMessage(BatchProcessor.java:359)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1541.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy204.receiveMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1540.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run(MethodInvokingRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:453)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.TimerManagerTaskScheduler$TimerScheduledFuture.timerExpired(TimerManagerTaskScheduler.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.TimerImpl.callListenerMethod(TimerImpl.java:298)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.GenericTimer.run(GenericTimer.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:264)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:495)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:131)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:335)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1146)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.TimerImpl.runListenerAsCJWork(TimerImpl.java:425)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.fireAlarm(_Alarm.java:333)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:230)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage3CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1217)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:991)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:913)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:293)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1009)
    ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is a WebSphere MQ resource oproblem, let's try to answer your questions in turn.

*Why this (Exception in Thread 2, at step B6) exception happened?

Why did Thread 2 encounter a stage3CommitProcessing exception?

How could I get more details about it?*

Chances are that the QMgr involved has not been configured with sufficient log space to contain all the messages that are under syncpoint.  Although you have taken care to serialize access to the database, the queue is not serialized and so the QMgr must manage up to 2000 records under syncpoint at once.  More details are available in the QMgr's error log.

*How to debug such transaction related race scenario?

Are there Websphere related logs that I could enable to see what made the commit fail during stage3?*

Take a look in `/var/mqm/qmgrs/[QMgr name]/errors/AMQERR01.log` for details of whether it was WebSphere MQ that rolled back the transaction.

Also, print the JMS linked exceptions.  Always.  JMS provides a multi-level exception where the lower levels contain provider-specific error information.  Often these convey to the application the same information you would otherwise have to go digging through the QMgr's error logs to get.

If I'm correct about the cause of the problem, the easiest way to test it is to have two instances try to read 100 records each under syncpoint.

*How it could be avoided/resolved?*

Size the logs so that they can contain all of the messages that might be under syncpoint at any given moment.  For example, if the messages are each 1k in size and you need 1000 of them under syncpoint for each of 10 instances, you will need at a minimum about 10MB of log extents.  These are defined by the QMgr's Primary and Secondary log size and count settings.  Remember that the QMgr also maintains syncpoints, for example when managing channels, and so whatever space you calculate needs to take into account channel batch sizes and a few MB for QMgr internal transactions.

Please see the section in the Infocenter on [calculating log file sizes](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q018470_.htm) for more detail.  For more background, please see [*Circular vs. Linear Logs*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0904_mismes/0904_mismes.html) in IBM developerWorks.